# IIS URL Rewrite rule to forward to api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web, iis

I host vue.js and asp.net core on the same Server.
My admins only allow to get traffic through port 443/https.
Therefore I'm trying to get a ReverseProxy(?) to run.

All traffic to `https://pim.test.de` should go to the site of this web.config. But traffic that goes to a link containing `/api/` like `https://pim.test.de/api/service/getinfoall`
should be forwarded to the site on port 44310, where the ASP.net core application is reachable. So internally it should reroute the request to `https://pim.test.de:44310/api/service/getinfoall`

What am I doing wrong?

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <rule name="redirecting to port 44310">
          <match url="/api/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://pim.test.de:44310/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: You can put the two together in a single project and deploy. Try out the template first, https://medium.com/@alexandre.malavasi/update-template-vue-js-asp-net-core-3-1-visual-studio-2019-caf13caab34b and then copy/paste your code over.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the response, but this isn't an option in this case. One of the main reasons is the fact, that we splitted the huge backend into multiple microservices which use a gateway, to reduce downtimes, better independent development, smaller organizable codebases and so on. For the Frontend we use a special CLI from the quasar.dev framework, which also isn't compatible with a asp.net project.

Comment: Then please use FRT to learn what's wrong with your rules, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules In a glance you set a wrong value in `match` tag, as the request URL doesn't start with `/`.

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped getting it to work :)

Comment: If you got it working already, then post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lex Li had the right solution. I just had to remove the `\` before `api` in the `match` tag.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="redirecting to port 44310">
          <match url="api/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://pim.test.de:44310/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```